# Rails route problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    ...
  end
```

Mu routes.rb

```
match '/user/:id/profile/edit', :to => 'users#edit', :as => "user_profile_edit", :via => "get"
```

My link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icons/run.png"), user_profile_edit_path %>
```

Exception:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing /profile/ from your route. Also make sure you have setup the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the user record.
Assuming the record is assigned to `@user`

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icons/run.png"), user_profile_edit_path(@user) %>
```